# Как отключить AsyncTask при его работе

Tags: java, android

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.recyclerView) RecyclerView recyclerView;
    AdapterMainActivity adapterMainActivity;
    List<Music> listAdapters = new ArrayList<Music>();
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient;
    String SEARCH_KEYWORD = "";
    @BindView(R.id.progressLoader) ProgressBar progressLoader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        adapterMainActivity = new AdapterMainActivity(this, listAdapters);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterMainActivity);
        okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.m_main_activity, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                if (newText.length() >= 5) {
                    SEARCH_KEYWORD = newText;
                    adapterMainActivity.clear();
                    new Async().execute();
                } else {
                    if (newText.length() < 5) {
                        adapterMainActivity.clear();
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }


    //**********************************Class Loader PlayList**********************************
    class Async extends AsyncTask {
        GsonMainActivity gsonMainActivity;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressLoader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=" + SEARCH_KEYWORD)
                    .build();

            try {
                Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();

                gsonMainActivity = new GsonBuilder()
                        .create()
                        .fromJson(response.body().string(), GsonMainActivity.class);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            listAdapters.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < gsonMainActivity.results.size(); i++) {
                Music music = new Music(
                        gsonMainActivity.results.get(i).artistName,
                        gsonMainActivity.results.get(i).trackName,
                        gsonMainActivity.results.get(i).artworkUrl100,
                        gsonMainActivity.results.get(i).previewUrl
                );

                listAdapters.add(music);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            super.onPostExecute(o);
            adapterMainActivity.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, listAdapters.size());
            progressLoader.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

clear Adapter

```
       public void clear(){
    int size = this.listMusic.size();
    this.listMusic.clear();
    notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
}
```

Когда я пишу в search слово по буквам с паузой в 3 сек. То все работает хорошо. Но если начинаю писать сразу без остановки то вываливается ошибка

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{527536ac position=40 id=-1, oldPos=0, pLpos:0 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached not recyclable(1) no parent}

Я понимаю что проблема кроется в asyncTask, хотя ошибка в RecyclerView происходит, но я думаю если решить проблему с AsyncTask то и в RecyclerView все отлично будет. Было бы не плохо понять как вырубить поток asyncTask, даже если он выполняется.

Или же лучше будет сделать мне некий таймер типо если я не пишу в течении 1 сек. То тогда запускается AsyncTask? А если человек опять писать начнет, а AsyncTask выполняется. Думаю правильнее будет вырубить asyncTask Если пользователь начал что - то писать.

Подскажите как это сделать и правильно ли я мыслю?

Comment: Может будет [полезна статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/243853/) о организации поиска с online-запросами.

Comment: @pavlofff, спс но я уже cancel использовал. Просто когда cancel делаю надо было еще и лист очищять